# Python: Multiplying a 3x3 matrix to 3nx1 array without using loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to do a matrix multiplication (a 3x3 matrix) with a vector (3x1). The "problem" ist that every component of the vector is taken each one of another matrix and I do not know how to proceed. Is there any way to do it?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,1,0],[1,0,1]])

v1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
v2 = np.array([[5,6,7,8]])
v3 = np.array([[9,10,11,12]])
```

And I would like to multiply: A x {1,5,9}.T and save the result. Then A x {2,6,10}.T,  A x {3,7,11}.T and finally A x {4,8,12}.T. The lengths of arrays v1, v2, and v3 are the same.

Thank you in advance!
Regards,

Xabi

Comment: Even showing your worst attempt gives us reason to think you've tried to solve it; it also helps us to understand what you've got in your mental toolbox which allows us to give you a more usable answer.

Comment: do not see why you would want to do this with or without for loops.   numpy has methods for matrix multiplication and Transposition.   you are already importing numby why not just use it.  it has C optimised, tested code exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the operation you are after with a single matrix multiplication, if you first stack all your vectors together into a single array:

```
vectors = np.vstack((vv1, v2, v3))
products = np.dot(A, v)
```

And now `products[:, i]` (or `products.T[i]`, if you prefer) has the product of `A` with the `i`-th vector.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It is a good way to solve the "problem"!

Answer (score 2):

**Numpy Arrays:**

Using two numpy arrays; one 3 x 3 and one 3x1:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.ones((3,3))
>>> b=np.random.rand(3,1)
array([[ 0.08970952],
       [ 0.56447089],
       [ 0.57500698]])
```

If you want matrix multiplication you can use `dot`

```
>>> np.dot(a,b)
array([[ 1.22918739],
       [ 1.22918739],
       [ 1.22918739]])
```

If you want element wise muliplication you can use `*`

```
>>> a*b
array([[ 0.08970952,  0.08970952,  0.08970952],
       [ 0.56447089,  0.56447089,  0.56447089],
       [ 0.57500698,  0.57500698,  0.57500698]])
```

**Numpy Matrices:**

Note that if you are using numpy matrices then the `*` operator can be used for matrix multiplication:

```
>>> c = np.mat(a)   # converts from array to matrix
>>> d = np.mat(b)
>>> c*d
matrix([[ 1.22918739],
        [ 1.22918739],
        [ 1.22918739]])
```